# This function has a return type of 'Future<bool>'.Try adding a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this method for the onWillScope property, and VS Code informs me of the following:

> This function has a return type of 'Future', but doesn't end
>   with a return statement. Try adding a return statement, or changing
>   the return type to 'void'.

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home/config');
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
```

How should I correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: You've already got two suggestions for fixing it in that message. Explain first why neither of those is suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add async to the method. this is asynchronous code: An async function runs synchronously until the first await keyword. This means that within an async function body, all synchronous code before the first await keyword executes immediately.

read more about this here : https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home/config');
  }
```

also onwillpop must return a future bool like so and that's why your method doesn't make much sense to the onwillpop

```
 onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this---->

```
onWillPop: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (__) => AppointmentList()));
              return Future.value(true);
            }
```